# Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the target's entitlements file

Tags: xcode8, icloud, ios10.2

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_iCloud_Storage_in_an_iOS_8_Application) on how to make an app that saves user generated data in iCloud. However, I'm running into this issue, and am so confused about what I need to do. Please help

[image: Xcode screenshot]

The first error says

> Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "iCloudStore" target's entitlements file.
>   Remove the entitlements or switch to manual signing and resolve the issue by downloading a provisioning profile from the developer website.

and the second one says

> Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.Kaen.TravisCloudStore" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers entitlement.

Comment: how did this issue solved for you i am not able to understand

Comment: Did you find solution? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're using your "Developer" profile and not your "Distribution" profile. Also make sure your app name is unique.

Comment: i am using the developer profile but still i am facing this issue any idea

Comment: I am using Ionic and removed and added the platform for iOS. That usually solves the issues but not this time.

Comment: I am trying to test push notifications and the the test app will not build without an APNS certificate. Situation developing...

Comment: I had a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client and i'm trying to use FCM. The build is probably failing because I do not have and APNs certificate yet.

Comment: Same here, push notifications were needed, but not enabled in "capabilities" of the project. That solved it for me.

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem.  Went to Target/Capabilities. Turned the following "On" - iCloud, In-App Purchase, Background Modes.  Problem solved.

Comment: I don't have that in my  Target/Capabilities.

Comment: I did turn on only Push Notification and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Remove DerivedData of your project and clean your project, then, reopen your Xcode.

Comment: That did it!  The path is ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Answer (score 1):

When you using Push notification in your iOS app. Ensure push notification is enabled or not in xcode "CAPABILITIES".

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked to go to Build settings and Select All and Combined and remove any values in the Code Signing Entitlements for Debug and Release.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I tried to use the NSPersistentCloudKitContainer example project from apple (CoreDataCloudKitDemo).

In my case, I also got an error when I opened the CloudKit Dashboard and tried to access the CoreDataCloudKitDemo container.

After deselecting the container and then CloudKit under the iCloud capability of the Xcode project and then reselecting CloudKit and the container again the error disappeared immediately.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my issue with the demo project!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by going to the Capabilities Tab to enable Remote Notification under the Background Modes. This is because I used Google FCM for my notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this, and had to delete ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\Profiles

via here: [Xcode 8.3 / Xcode 9.0 Refresh provisioning profile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060482/xcode-8-3-xcode-9-0-refresh-provisioning-profile-devices)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Select your icloud container issue will be solved .