# Xcode 8.3 / Xcode 9.0 Refresh provisioning profile devices

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have added some new devices. How can I refresh the provisioning profile, as Xcode 8 automatically manages signing assets?

I have found this question: [Refresh devices in team provisioning profile managed by Xcode 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729193/refresh-devices-in-team-provisioning-profile-managed-by-xcode-7) – but we can't do that in Xcode 8.3.

I don't have the device with me so I manually added it in the portal and also edited the provisioning profile but Xcode is not re-downloading it.

Answer (score 310, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

1. Go to `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/` and delete all the provisioning profiles from there.
2. Go to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts and select the Apple ID.
3. Click  `Download Manual Profiles` or `Download All Profiles`. And it will download all the provisioning profiles again.

[image: Download Profiles button]

Comment: What a hassle for such an easy task. Every new xcode version the shortcut to refreshing the prov profiles seems to be removed. Thanks for this

Comment: I can't find any `MobileDevice` folder in `Library`

Comment: @Ionut use terminal to open this folder: `open ~/Library/MobileDevice`

Comment: If the app is open in Xcode, and you can match the date of the provisioning profile in ~/Library, you can delete one profile and by the time you've returned to Xcode, the profile has already being used.

Comment: omg what the hell apple, always put us in embarrassing situations with clients.

Comment: is this the right way to go also with Xcode 9? c'mon Apple?!

Comment: @MatterGoal yes it is!

Comment: @RenePot well... this is sad. They should provide a better way.

Comment: been struggling with this for hours, absurd. updated to iOS 12 and Xcode 10 and now my Profile is always None. tried everything, removed provisioning profiles and downloaded them again from Xcode. even revoked certs and created new ones. nothing works. older packages validate just fine, I need to release a new version and I'm stuck. what the hell do I do.

Comment: btw, for all non-mac users like me - Library is a hidden folder, you can open it via terminal by using: `open ~/Library/MobileDevice/"Provisioning Profiles"`

Answer (score 97):

Remove the **.mobileprovision** file for the app this way :

The command in the terminal is : `rm`

[image]

Comment: this forces you to use a new bundle id on Xcode 8.x

Comment: @vishaldharankar No, this has nothing to do with the bundle id

Comment: when you delete the profiles it tries to register as a new app and generate profiles and thus when it uses existing bundle id which is already registered it gives error.

Comment: jesus, it never ever crossed my mind that I could do something like this, thank you very much!

Comment: @Erik-Mueller haha, I can relate :D try dragging the tiny file icon on top of any open file (e.g. pdf or text file) for accessing the file itself :D THAT blew my mind..

Answer (score 27):

Step 1. Click on desktop then from top menu **Go** > **Go to Folders...**

[image]

Step 2. **Write/Paste** following path and enter:

> ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\Profiles

[image]

Step 3. Select **Provisioning Profiles** folder and delete all provisions profiles in it

[image]

Step 4. Go to xCode **Preference** > **Accounts** > **Apple ID** and then click on **Download Manual Profiles** button

[image]

Comment: The first image solved my search. I didn't know where to find 'MobileDevice' folder . I tried with finder for path `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/` but no luck, this ended my search.

Comment: I had to restart Xcode after doing this to get this to work.  (Possibly I could have just restarted Xcode)

Comment: Thanks.  I needed to do this after upgrading to Xcode Version 13.0.

Answer (score 8):

First delete the provisioning profile from `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\Profiles/` , then edit provisioning profile from **developer portal** and select all **devices** while editing Provisioning profile. Then download this profile and open in your **Xcode**.

Answer (score 5):

To add devices to your provisioning profile in Xcode 8 with automatic code signing, you simply need to build to the device in Xcode.  Xcode will add the device's UDID and regenerate the provisioning profile automatically.  If you don't have physical access to the device, I don't think there is a way to add it to your provisioning profile without going back to manually managing your devices and profiles.

Comment: This won't work for phones you don't have access to though

Comment: That is true, My answer was to the original question, which made no mention of not having the device and manually managing the provisioning profile.  The original question stated just that they were using Automatic Code Signing (they apparently aren't).