# How to see the downloaded provisioning profile in xcode 8.3.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

How to see the downloaded provisioning profile in xcode 8.3.2? Previously there was a see details button for every added team in xcode. Now I can see a `manage certificate` button which will list all certificates. Where can I see the downloaded profiles? Is there any way to see the profiles inside xcode? I know we can goto `~Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` folder and check this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Xcode 8.3.2 you can only see the name of the profile and created and expiry date.`Project Settings > Select Target` In signing section press the  [image] icon in front of the Provisioning Profile.

If you just wan't to know that latest profile profile has been download or not. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44061528/1825618

Comment: Thanks Bilal, SO the only way is to delete all profiles and re-download.  Anyways it works.

Comment: I have faced the similar issue recently, I couldn't find any other solution so far, only re-downlaoding worked for me.