# Build Failed on Microsoft app center

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, azure-pipelines, bundle-identifier, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to make a build on Microsoft app center and my repository have connected from VSTS but I am facing this error its not my bundle id I have using another one bundle id in my project that is live on App store. but I can't understand how this error are showing.

Info.plist : error : Project bundle identifier 'com.companyname.Relyfy' does not match specified provisioning profile '83b9c1b7-ad1a-48c4-8322-6e4cff2dc90a' [/Users/vsts/agent/2.131.0/work/1/s/Relyfy/iOS/Relyfy.iOS.csproj]
Done Building Project "/Users/vsts/agent/2.131.0/work/1/s/Relyfy/iOS/Relyfy.iOS.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"/Users/vsts/agent/2.131.0/work/1/s/Relyfy/iOS/Relyfy.iOS.csproj" (Rebuild target) (1) ->
(_DetectSigningIdentity target) -> 
  Info.plist : error : Project bundle identifier 'com.companyname.Relyfy' does not match specified provisioning profile '83b9c1b7-ad1a-48c4-8322-6e4cff2dc90a' [/Users/vsts/agent/2.131.0/work/1/s/Relyfy/iOS/Relyfy.iOS.csproj]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue when trying to release my app to the app store using AppCenter.ms. The issue I had was that when setting up the AppCenter app, someone had selected the wrong app in the App Store to associate it with.

**In my case the solution was:**

1. Go to AppCenter -> [My App Name] -> Distribute -> Stores, select the 3 dots next to the App Store connection and click "Delete Connection".
   [image: App Center delete connection]
2. Once the old app is deleted, click "Connect to Store".
3. Log in with an Apple ID with access to this app.
4. Select the appropriate app.
5. Now you're done.

**Still not working for you?**

- If that doesn't do the trick, the problem is that the App Store connection does not match the Bundle ID of the app that AppCenter is building.
- To find what Bundle ID your app is being built with, search the build logs of the failing build for "application-identifier". The line after that line will be `<string><YOUR_PROJECT_ID>.my.bundle.id.here</string>`, where `my.bundle.id.here` is your Bundle ID>
- Now go into appstoreconnect.apple.com and verify your Bundle ID matches the app you're trying to build:
  [image]

Comment: thanks effectively if you have a dev and prod app (our case) you have to add 2 app and connect each time to different store.
Thank you very much for this answer this avoid me some time spent to find this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried contacting our support team? Just click the chat dialog in the lower right-hand corner.

For this particular error were you able to build locally?

Also, this support document might help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/ios/uploading-signing-files

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't built successfully, it's not the problem of App Center. From your error message, we can know it was the issue of your provisioning profile.

You said you were using another bundle identifier, have you also downloaded the corresponding provisioning profile? Without it you can't deploy on a real device.

You can download it with XCode: Go to XCode > Preferences > Accounts > Add an Apple ID(which contains this bundle ID), then download all profiles. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44061528/8354952) for more details.

Besides you also need the corresponding certification both public key and private key. Export the p12 file on the original Mac which creates the certification and install it on your Mac. At last you can build your project with **another one bundle id**.

After you have followed all the steps above, you can configure your iOS project using Xamarin Forms: right click your ios project -> Properties -> at iOS Bundle Signing tab, choose the correct signing and provisioning profile you just installed above.