# Cannot update provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode

A team member needed to register her device so I added her device to Devices section of Apple Dev Portal. I then created a new ad hoc provisioning profile that includes her device and finally deleted the old provisioning profile. But XCode doesn't seem to see this new provisioning profile:
[image]

To ensure that Apple is using the latest profile I did this:

```
rm -rF /Users/etayluz/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
```

And when I try to build Xcode errors out:

```
error: Build input file cannot be found: '~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/dab00c70-5073-403b-ae60-e337afeee7fc.mobileprovision'
```

How do I get Xcode to use the new ad hoc provisioning profile?

I also clicked on "Download Manual Profiles" in Preferences->Accounts - and that does fetch the new profile that I've created - but Xcode is being stupid and still demanding to use the older profile. How do I get Xcode to point and start looking for new profile?

Comment: try this very powerful , only rm old provisioning file
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49953569/13377344

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go to ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/ and delete all the provisioning profiles from there.
2. Go to XCode > Preferences > Accounts and select the Apple Id.
3. Click Download All Profiles. And it will download all the provisioning profiles again.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is how to get Xcode to recognize that it needs to use this new provisioning profile. I have no problem getting Xcode to download it

Comment: After downloading the new provisioning profile, you have to double click on that. It will automatically import into Xcode. 
Provisioning profile matches the *bundle identifier*, with the help of identifer, Xcode recognize where to import the new provisioning profile.

Comment: I had to Delete Derived data and restarting Xcode as well.

Comment: I have double clicked the new provisioning file. but now I am getting Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/~~~.mobileprovision'.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Xcode->Preferences->Accounts
2. Select the Apple ID and then select the Team which your app is from.
3. Click on Download Manual profiles
4. CMD+Shift+K (Clean Project)
5. Build Project again (CMD + B)