# Where is the `Share Extension Profile` in apple's develop website

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, share-extension

I know where to find the `extension provision profile` [through Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49953569/1530581), and they all list in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

My question is how could I found the `extension provision profile` in apple's develop website ?

Looks like https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list only list the app's profile.

#### Why need manual Profile

Since I setup in CodeMagic as manual sign with uploaded manual `.p12` & `profiles`. 
So I need upload two manual profiles which all need to get download from apple's develop website, copy from local profiles folder `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` just not work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, there's the answer:

1. Xcode will `automatic generate profile` when you Share Extension just created.
2. If you want `manual profile`, then just need to `create a profile` on `apple's develop site`
3. When creating select the `bundle id same as you input in Share Extension target`.