# The code signature version is no longer supported with Xcode 13

Tags: ios, xcode, capacitor

I get the message `Unable to install "App"` when running my Xcode 13 project on a physical iPhone running iOS 15. If I click "Details", I see the below information (most notably `The code signature version is no longer supported`). This issue appears to happen to some people running Xcode 12. However, I am running Xcode 13.2.1 and macOS Monterey 12.1.

I have Xcode automatically manage signing under my development team. Today, I edited my App ID Configuration in the Apple Developer Console to add Sign-in With Apple, and got the following message: `Adding or removing any capabilities will invalidate any provisioning profiles that include this App ID and they must be regenerated for future use.` I suspect this is the cause of my problem, but am not sure what to do to fix it.

Things I have tried:

- Clean build folder
- [`--generate-entitlement-der` in code signing options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68467307/10868905)
- [Change frameworks to "Do not Embed"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69588949/10868905)
- Disable `automatically manage signing` and use a newly-generated provisioning profile
- [Refreshed provisioning profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060482/xcode-8-3-xcode-9-0-refresh-provisioning-profile-devices)

```
Details

Unable to install "App"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-02-10 03:33:39 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
The code signature version is no longer supported.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008029)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011739c076 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001173da6e8 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001094b1fb4 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001173da432 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1420
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011093b9ea __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 3508
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001095e698b __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001095e80f7 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 931
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff812d35ad8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff812d36cc9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff812d3ccee _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 696
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff812d3d7c8 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff812d477e1 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 758
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff812eea074 _pthread_wqthread + 326
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff812ee8ffb start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone12,5";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.2.1 (19C63)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 4457;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402620375";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.5.2";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.2";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.2";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.1 (Build 21C52)
Xcode 13.2.1 (19586) (Build 13C100)
Timestamp: 2022-02-09T21:33:39-06:00
```

Comment: I suppose you already tried leaving automatic signing turned on?  Does the problem arise if you start from scratch and build a new app?  Some of my projects are quite old and have settings you wouldn't use on a new app.

Comment: I have tried disabling automatic signing. Still has the same issue. However, starting from scratch with a new project seems to build and run fine as you suggested. Not sure what the difference would be

Comment: I just re-cloned this project and was able to build and run it. Based on that I'm guessing Xcode had some sort of project-specific cache that was causing this issue

Comment: I have a newly cloned project and I still get this error. Will try to reclone as well but not expecting anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It ended up being that Xcode needed to be cleaned

Select `Menu Bar > Product > Clean`

Or use the command: `⌘ + ⇧ + K`