# nfc_manager isAvailable returns false iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I followed this tutorial https://medium.com/flutter-community/nfc-with-flutter-f8c3515cb0e0 and still got false when calling `NfcManager.instance.isAvailable`, what am I doing wrong?

updated capability in xcode
[image]

updated profile in https://developer.apple.com/account
[image]

set NFCReaderUsageDescription in info.plst
[image]

I also synced my provisining profile as described here [Xcode 8.3 / Xcode 9.0 Refresh provisioning profile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060482/xcode-8-3-xcode-9-0-refresh-provisioning-profile-devices). Does anybody have an idea what I did wrong. I'm trying it on a iPhone 13 mini.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue…
add this to your .entitlements file

```
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
        <string>TAG</string>
    </array>
```

and assign the right `.entitlements` file to your `code signing entitlements` file (runner -> Build Settings)